# How to generate an excerpt for a specific field in Search API Solr?

Tags: search

I created a custom query that displays publications based on keywords entered by user. The query looks into "title", "body" and "author title"(node reference) fields.

```
 if(empty($keywords)!=1){
      $index = search_api_index_load("index_all");
      $query=new SearchApiQuery($index);
      $query->condition('type', 'publications', '=');
      $query->condition('language', $language->language, '=');
      $query->fields(array('title', 'field_author:title', 'body:value')); 
      $query->range(0, 30);
      $query->keys($keywords);
      $data=$query->execute();
      $results=$data['results'];

      if(empty($results)!=1){
        print '<h3>'.t('Publications').'</h3>';
        foreach ($results as $key => $result) {
          $alias = drupal_get_path_alias('node/'.$result['entity']->nid);
          print '<div class="search-row"><div class="search-title"><a href="'.$alias.'">'.$result['fields']['title'].'</a></div>';
          print '<div class="search-excerpt">'.$result['excerpt'].'</div></div>';
        }
      }
    }
```

Everything works well except the excerpt generated.

I don't know why, excerpt seems to be generated in conjunction with "author name" and "body field", I mean every time. Even if the author name hasn't any of keywords, he is printed every time. For example with keyword "tax", I get this:

> Corporate **Tax** Reform International
>
> Pierre-Marie Glauser Corporate **Tax** Reform International ...

The second line is generated by `print '<div class="search-excerpt">'.$result['excerpt'].'</div></div>';`

As you can see, the author name "Pierre-Marie Glauser" appears in excerpt, but it is not concerned by keyword "tax".

Also if I disable the title from excerpt in admin UI:

[image]

The author name doesn't appear anymore in excerpt!!! For example if the query is "Glauser", I have no excerpt generated (when I had if the title is enabled for excerpt..). Something seems buggy there, it's like "title" and "author name" fields are stucked.

I don't want to exclude author name completely from excerpt. I just want to exclude it when keyword is not matching with it. For example if the keyword is "Pierre-Marie" or "Glauser", the author name should appear in excerpt. Same for title. Only display title if it's matching with keyword

How to get selective excerpts programmatically. For example, is it possible to generate an excerpt for "title" field and another one for "author name" field separately?